# How can I reconstruct a network so that it maintains the same attributes and same shape but the nodes are in different locations?

Tags: r, igraph

I currently have a network that is similar in node count and edge count to the following:

```
 set.seed(12)
 net <- sample_gnp(20, 1/4)
 V(net)$a <- sample(c(0, 1), vcount(net), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
 V(net)$b <- sample(c(0, 1), vcount(net), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
 V(net)$color <- V(net)$a + 4
 plot(net)
```

This creates a distinct network with a unique shape. Is there a way that I can only move the 20 nodes in this network randomly and maintain the shape? I want the network to look the same visually but with different nodes (node A at coordinate (a, b) is replaced by node G and they have the same number of edges). So ideally I want the graph to make a change like the following: (Same proportion of yellow to blue nodes but you can tell that they've moved around while simultaneously maintaining the shape)

[image: Change after Rearrangement]

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Would it work for you to get all nodes and edges at the same place, but different labels on the nodes?

Comment: @G5W, I want to keep the nodes and edges at the same place but all the attribute values are randomly reassigned (I want the attributes to stick together for this so all the attributes for node A will remain together as a group and the new node that gains these values will be exactly like node A just in a different position)

Comment: @G5W I edited my question to better demonstrate what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to add the layout as additional node attributes, which are kept constant.

```
  l <- layout_nicely(net)
  V(net)$x <- l[,1]
  V(net)$y <- l[,2]
```

The other attributes are reshuffled following the *same* pattern in order to keep the attribute bundle intact.

```
  pattern <- sample(1:vcount(net))
  net2 <- net
  V(net2)$a <- V(net2)$a[pattern]
  V(net2)$b <- V(net2)$b[pattern]
  V(net2)$color <- V(net2)$color[pattern]
```

Now if you plot the result, you will hopefully end up with the desired output.

```
  par(mfrow = c(1,2))
  plot(net)
  plot(net2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but here are a couple of other options.

### Rotate the graph

```
LO = layout_nicely(net)

LO2 = LO
alpha=pi/4
LO2[,1] =  cos(alpha)*LO[,1] + sin(alpha)*LO[,2]
LO2[,2] = -sin(alpha)*LO[,1] + cos(alpha)*LO[,2]

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(net, layout=LO)
plot(net, layout=LO2)
```

[image: Rotated graph]

### Flip side to side

```
LO3 = LO
alpha=pi/4
LO3[,1] = -LO3[,1]
plot(net, layout=LO)
plot(net, layout=LO3)
```

[image: Flipped Graph]